# ‘dict’ object has no attribute ‘headers’ ошибка при get запросе к датчику

Tags: python

пишу программку в обучающих целях
есть датчик https://tasmota.github.io/docs/Commands/#with-mqtt
по документации обращаться на вкл/выкл его через ip
http//cm?cmnd=Power%20On
http//cm?cmnd=Power%20off

на джанго делают маленький сайт, что бы управлять датчиком.
написал функцию get что бы датчик включался, выключался
когда я к ней обращаюсь через веб запрос (http://127.0.0.1:8000/interaction/commands/off_sensor/?), то срабатывание датчика происходит, но выдает ошибку ‘dict’ object has no attribute ‘headers’

```
def on_sensor(res_on):
url_sensor1 = 'http://192.168.0.89/'
on = 'cm?cmnd=Power%20On'
res_on = requests.get(url_sensor1+on)
print(res_on)
res_on.raise_for_status()
JsonResponse = res_on.json()
print(JsonResponse)
return JsonResponse
```

может кто подскажет куда копать?

Comment: выложите весь Traceback ошибки

Comment: Блин, что с кодом, почему после функции нету табуляции ? Это я чего то не понимаю?

Answer (score 0):

разобрался.
функция возвращала словарь, а нужно вернуть объект класса JsonResponse

```
def on_sensor(res_on):
url_sensor1 = 'http://192.168.0.89/'
on = 'cm?cmnd=Power%20On'
res_on = requests.get(url_sensor1+on)
# print(res_on)
res_on.raise_for_status()
result_dict = res_on.json()
# print(result_dict)
return JsonResponse(result_dict)
```